# Create progress bar for download zip

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

I want to create a progress bar in a backgroud progress when the users download zip's or same. This is my code:

```
    private void DoSincroFit()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

        //Add headers to request
        request.Headers["Type"] = "sincrofit";
        request.Headers["Device"] = "1";
        request.Headers["Version"] = "0.000";
        request.Headers["Os"] = "WindowsPhone";

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(playResponseAsync), request);
    }

    public async void playResponseAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        //Declaration of variables
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            string fileName = "sincrofit.rar";

            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                var newZipFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                using (var writeStream = await newZipFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (var outputStream = writeStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                    {
                        using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                        {
                            using (Stream input = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                var totalSize = 0;
                                for (int size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); size > 0; size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
                                {
                                    dataWriter.WriteBytes(buffer);
                                    totalSize += size;    //get the progress of download

                                    //I think the progress bar going here!
                                }
                                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                                await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                                dataWriter.DetachStream();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
            dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                //Declaration of variables
                SMethods.Message_Dialog("Download has stopped!", "Error");
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is method that call background method

```
    public async Task<string> doSync(ProgressBar bar)
    {
        //Declaration of variables
        string response = await DoRequest("CHECK", "1", "0.000", "WindowsPhone");
        pBar = bar;

        //When is 1, the checkConnection will connect
        if (response == "1")
        {
            response = response + "," + await DoRequest("SIZEFIT", "1", "0.000", "WindowsPhone");

            DoSincroFit();
            response += "," + await DoRequest("DELSINC", "1", "0.000", "WindowsPhone");

            return response;
        }

        return "0,0,0";
    }
```

How can I create progress bar when this is a external class? Exactly, doSync and DoSincroFit belong a Sync.cs and my UI is MyPage.Xaml.cs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i can solve this! My progress bar do work now!

```
    private void DoSincroFit()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

        //Add headers to request
        request.Headers["Type"] = "sincrofit";
        request.Headers["Device"] = "1";
        request.Headers["Version"] = "0.000";
        request.Headers["Os"] = "WindowsPhone";

        //Windows Cache Problems
        request.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
        request.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";

        dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(playResponseAsync), request);
    }

    public async void playResponseAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        //Declaration of variables
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            //For download file  with stream
            string fileName = "sincrofit.rar";

            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

                //For acces Local folder of phone device
                var newZipFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                //Progress bar and their update
                using (var writeStream = await newZipFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (var outputStream = writeStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                    {
                        using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                        {
                            using (Stream input = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                var totalSize = 0;
                                int read;

                                uint zeroUint = Convert.ToUInt32(0);
                                uint readUint;

                                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                                {
                                    totalSize += read; 

                                    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                                    {
                                        //Declaration of variables
                                        pBar.Value = totalSize * 100 / sizeFit;
                                    });

                                    readUint = Convert.ToUInt32(read);
                                    IBuffer ibuffer = buffer.AsBuffer();
                                    dataWriter.WriteBuffer(ibuffer, zeroUint, readUint);
                                }

                                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                                await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                                dataWriter.DetachStream();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //For control errors stopped progress bar
            dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                //Declaration of variables
                SMethods.Message_Dialog("Download has stopped!", "Error");
            });
        }
    }
```

This is a test progress bar but if u need download a big zip's then use buffer with 1024 or same... Because with 1 byte can be terrible! Thanks for all! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM you might create properties that notify when they are changed. Then, your external code which shouldn't really know anything about UI representation simply updates such properties.

Then, in your UI code you bind controls to those properties.

Without knowing more about your application, I cannot offer anything concrete here.